# Как убрать вторую полосу под TitleBar? И откуда она взялась?

Tags: android, design

Вопрос, вероятно, глуп. Но что-то я не могу его решить: есть ActionBarActivity, и в нем  под TitleBar'ом откуда-то берется вторая  похожая полоса. В layout'e ничего о ней  не сказано. Как ее убрать? Вот скрин: https://yadi.sk/i/A3ZyOUM7bw94A

Comment: на 4.0 есть, на 2.3 её нет )

Comment: Насколько я знаю, на 2.3 нет и Titlebar. Меня же интересует только вторая полоска под ним, и то, как ее убрать.

Comment: Оу, я вообще подумал про тень в экшн баре. А вы про маргин. Разметку надо смотреть. btw, есть actionbarsherlock для 2.3

Comment: Вообще проблема на самом деле оказалась более чем глупая. Я в OnCreate давно написал кой-чего с некоторой целью, которую решил позже иначе. "Кой-чего" вот:
final ActionBar bar = getActionBar(); 
bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
Отсюда все проблемы, всем спасибо, что откликнулись на мой вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вас правильно понял, то вам необходимо просто заменить родителя вашей активности на обыкновенный "Activity".
Т.е смените "ActionBarActivity" на "Activity".

Далее можете сменить тему активности, TitleBar которой вам мешает. Делается это в манифесте. По умолчанию в ресурсах создается шаблон темы. Т.е вам достаточно будет просто пробежаться по манифесту и заменить шаблонную тему на, например, стандартную, поставляемую Android( `android.R.*` ).

Если загляните в стилевые ресурсы, то должны будете обнаружить следующее:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

Это и есть тот самый шаблон, который, как можно заменить, является наследником подмножества тем `Theme.AppCompat.*`.

Comment: На превью в редактировании Layout у меня все как надо: https://yadi.sk/i/yNF1dcXWbwA2e . А именно: сразу за titlebar идет layout. При запуске приложения появляется полоса как на скрине в вопросе. В style описана тема Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar . Ваш ответ, я так понял о том, как убрать тайтл, но мне не нужно его убирать. Вот скрин где видна разница https://yadi.sk/i/5pI_u923bwAUE

Comment: Хм, пардон, неправильно понял. Что ж, на скрине та линия вовсе не выглядит, как "второй тайтл". Вероятно, это просто незаполненное место. Ниже вы, вроде бы, используете какое-то изображение. Так вот, быть может, оно просто занимает не все отведенной пространство?

Comment: Ниже activity со своим Layout, где есть Background. Занимает все отведенное место. Проблема, к слову, была и тогда, когда ниже было пустое activity.

Comment: Решил проблему.